# Why does my Ti-84 CE Plus not have a wait command in the program menu under CNTRL?

Tags: calculator, wait, missing-data

I'm trying to add a small delay in a program that I'm writing on my TI-84 CE Plus, and the programming guide that I found from Texas Instruments says that it should be A in the CNTRL menu, but it's just not there. Is there any way to re-add the command back?

I tried to look through other menus and looking up why this could be, but I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Is the command visible in the Catalog (if I remember correctly, [2nd]+0)?

Comment: @nanofarad I'll have to get back to you on that on Monday, I lent my friend my calculator for the weekend

Comment: @nanofarad it does not show up